# Put a validator into the cell of an existing, already formatted sheet, using OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

How is a validator drop-down object placed into a cell of a formatted sheet that is already open by an OpenXML process?

I do have a routine that has to first open a document and create a new sheet before a validator is added, but I'm so far unable to integrate it into a sheet that is already open.  It's here:

```
public static void ForValidator() {
using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create("validator output.xlsx", SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook)) {
 WorkbookPart workbookpart = myDoc.AddWorkbookPart();
 workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();
 WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
 SheetData sheetData_ = new SheetData();
 worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData_);
 Sheets sheets_ = myDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
 sheets_.AppendChild(new Sheet() {
  Id = myDoc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(myDoc.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First()),
  SheetId = 1,
  Name = "Sheet1"
 });

 DataValidations dataValidations = new DataValidations();
 DataValidation dataValidation = new DataValidation() {
  Type = DataValidationValues.List,
  AllowBlank = true,
  SequenceOfReferences = new ListValue<StringValue>() { InnerText = "F11" }
 };
 Formula1 formula = new Formula1();
 formula.Text = "\"Selection 1,Selection 2,Selection 3\"";

 dataValidation.Append(formula);
 dataValidations.Append(dataValidation);

 worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(dataValidations);
}
```

I'd rather like it to work like the following, a color filler that operates on an already open document and doesn't even need the name of the active sheet:

```
static Row getRow(uint rowIndex, WorksheetPart worksheetPart) {
 Worksheet worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
 SheetData sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
 Row row;
 if (sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).Count() != 0) {
 row = sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).First();
 }
 else {
  row = new Row() { RowIndex = rowIndex };
  sheetData.Append(row);
 }
 return row;
}

static void AddbackgroundFormat(SpreadsheetDocument document, Cell c, string colorCode) {
 Fills fs = AddFill(document.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Fills, colorCode);
 AddCellFormat(document.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats, document.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Fills);
 c.StyleIndex = (UInt32)(document.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Elements<CellFormat>().Count() - 1);
}

static Fills AddFill(Fills fills1, string colorCode) {
 Fill fill1 = new Fill();

 PatternFill patternFill1 = new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid };
 ForegroundColor foregroundColor1 = new ForegroundColor() { Rgb = colorCode };

 patternFill1.Append(foregroundColor1);

 fill1.Append(patternFill1);
 fills1.Append(fill1);
 return fills1;
}

static void AddCellFormat(CellFormats cf, Fills fs) {
 CellFormat cellFormat2 = new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = 0, FontId = 0, FillId = (UInt32)(fs.Elements<Fill>().Count() - 1), BorderId = 0, FormatId = 0, ApplyFill = true };
 cf.Append(cellFormat2);
}

Row row1 = getRow(11, worksheetPart);
foreach (Cell c2 in row1.Elements<Cell>()) {
 if (c2.CellReference.Value == "F11") {
  AddbackgroundFormat(document, c2, "ff0000");
 }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE:
My latest attempt, and nothing works.  It doesn't crash, but it doesn't create a validator either:

```
    DataValidations dataValidations1 = new DataValidations(){ Count = (UInt32Value)1U };
    DataValidation dataValidation1 = new DataValidation(){ Type = DataValidationValues.List, AllowBlank = true, ShowInputMessage = true, ShowErrorMessage = true, SequenceOfReferences = new ListValue<StringValue>() { InnerText = "F11" } };
    Formula1 formula11 = new Formula1();
    formula11.Text = "\"item 1,item 2,item 3\"";
    dataValidation1.Append(formula11);
    dataValidations1.Append(dataValidation1);
    document.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Append(dataValidations1);
```

Comment: Have you tried creating two nearly identical spreadsheets, one with the validator and one without, and then comparing them using the OpenXML Productivity tool (the best gift an OOXML program can have)?

Comment: First I've heard of it.  (I probably ignored it when I installed the 2.5 libraries a few months ago.)  Since you recommended it, I'm reading great things about it and will do what you suggested.  Thanks.